# c# Data-Driven Approach

Tags: c#, class, oop, object

I have a main class Animal and 5 classes with animals and made polymorphism and work everything fine.I have a new requirement for solution like this:
`model the animals using a data-driven approach`. What is this meaning?

Comment: you might want to read eric lippers articles on [wizards and warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/)

Comment: From the article i understand that "data-driven" means result depend from  the input? ex function input et...

Comment: See also other questions tagged with [data-driven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-driven?tab=Votes), e.g [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802606/1997232) is quite good.